# Return data from another model in Laravel / Laravel Nova

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, laravel-nova

**My Question:**

> In Laravel Nova, how can I display the Country Name based on the
>   Country ID?

I have 2 tables:

1. countries
2. countries_price

---

1. countries table holds the `id, name` etc..
2. countries_price table holds `id, country_id, country_price`

---

**Models:** *(Laravel & Nova)*

In Country Model (Laravel):

```
    public function countryPrice() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\\CountryPrice');
    }
```

In CountryPrice Model (Laravel):

```
    public function countries()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Country', 'id', 'country_id');
    }
```

In Country Model (Nova):

```
HasOne::make('CountryPrice'),
```

In CountryPrice Model (Nova):

```
HasMany::make('Countries'),
```

---

**What I'm trying:**

In CountryPrice Model (Laravel)

```
    public function getCountryName() {
        return Country::where('id', $this->country_id)->first()->name;
    }
```

In CountryPrice Model (Nova)

```
    public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            ID::make()->sortable(),
            ID::make('Country ID','country_id'),

// TRYING TO PULL IN COUNTRY NAME HERE
            Text::make('Country Name', function () {
                $countryName= $this->getCountryName;
                return $countryName;
            }),

            Text::make('Base Price', 'trip_cost'),
            HasMany::make('Countries'),
        ];
    }
```

**My Error:**

> App\CountryPrice::getCountryName Must return a relationship instance

---

I don't understand the error and need help getting this to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updates based on your comments

It seems that you have a one to one relationship between Country and CountryPrice. It can be read as follows: "A Country has one CountryPrice and each CountryPrice belongs to one and only one Country".

That relationship can be set up with:
**Country Model**

```php
public function countryPrice()
{
    return $this->hasOne(CountryPrice::class);
}
```

**CountryPrice Model**

```php
public function country()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Country::class);
}
```

Then update the nova entities accordingly:
**Country Resource**

```php
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    return [
        // ...
        HasOne::make('Country Prices'),
        // ...
    ];
}
```

**CountryPrice Resource**

```php
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    return [
        // ...
        BelongsTo::make('Country'),
        // ...
    ];
}
```

Then specify the title property in the Country nova resource as I explained below in my old answer:

```php
/**
 * The single value that should be used to represent the resource when being displayed.
 *
 * @var string
 */
public static $title = 'name';
```

The resulting system will let you pick a single Country from a select box when you create a CountryPrice record from the nova interface. In the Country nova index you will also see each country with its assigned price.

I hope that is the correct behaviour that you need. If that's not correct let me know and I'll open a chat on Stack Overflow so we can sort out exactly what you need and solve the issue.

---

### Old Answer below

#### Fixing the relationships

I think your relationships are set up wrong. From the table schema you posted, it looks like that each `Country` can have many `CountryPrice` because you put the `country_id` column in the `country_prices`.

Therefore, if "Country has many Country Prices", then "Each CountryPrice belongs to a single Country".

> If I misinterpreted your relationship, let me know in the comments the correct one and I'll fix my answer.

You can set up these two relationships as follows:

**Country Model**

```php
public function countryPrices()
{
    return $this->hasMany(CountryPrice::class);
}
```

**CountryPrice Model**

```php
public function country()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Country::class);
}
```

Then update both Nova Resources to match the new relationships:

**Country Resource**

```php
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    return [
        // ...
        HasMany::make('Country Prices'),
        // ...
    ];
}
```

**CountryPrice Resource**

```php
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    return [
        // ...
        BelongsTo::make('Country'),
        // ...
    ];
}
```

---

#### Explaining the current exception

> App\CountryPrice::getCountryName Must return a relationship instance

The error you are getting has nothing to do with Nova itself. It happens because each (non static) method defined in a model should be either a query scope, a model accessor/mutator or a relationship.

This means that if you define the `getCountryName` it would be treated as a relationship and needs to return a relationship instance, but you are returning a string.

In your use case, you don't really need to define an accessor. You can use:

```php
$countryPrice->country->name
```

on a `CountryPrice` instance.

---

#### Fixing the Display Title

To fix the `Country` choices displayed in the `BelongsTo` select input on the `CountryPrice` resource, you have to define a `title` property or method that will be used exactly for that purpose in the Nova Resource class that you are linking to (`Country` in your example).

You could either use:

```php
/**
 * The single value that should be used to represent the resource when being displayed.
 *
 * @var string
 */
public static $title = 'name';
```

or, in case you need to compute the title property from other attributes/transformations:

```php
/**
 * Get the value that should be displayed to represent the resource.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function title()
{
    // You can make advanced transformations/processing of any value here
    // $this will refer to the current resource instance.
    return $this->name;
}
```

This would also apply on the global search.

---

**References**

Laravel One to Many relationship: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Laravel Accessors: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Nova Resource Title/Subtitle properties: https://nova.laravel.com/docs/2.0/search/global-search.html#title-subtitle-attributes

Comment: I changed around the relationships as you mentioned above and it worked great in Nova as it showed the Country Name in my Country Prices view.`..............`But the relationships I have are correct `..............` I have a list of every country in the world in my `Countries table`, and mark them as active for the ones we travel to.`..............`  The `CountryPrice` is a `Base Price` for those active countries and there can be only One Base Price Per Country. `..............`  This did help me understand how relationships work in general and in Nova. Thanks for explaining in such detail.

Comment: The only thing I still don't get is if a: "CountryPrice can be assigned to multiple Countries and each Country can have only one CountryPrice" (1 to many relationship) or "CountryPrice can be assigned to only one Country and each Country can has only one CountryPrice" (1 to 1 relationship). After I got that I'll fix the answer accordinglly

Comment: Here is an image of the 2 tables. Maybe this will help.`.....`
https://i.imgur.com/rXCV1qu.jpg `.....` So I guess this would be a 1 to 1 relationship. `.....` When I'm displaying the `country_base_prices` I want to use the `country_id` to bring in the `countries_table` `name`.

Comment: I have updated the answer to support the 1 to 1 relationship.  If that's not correct behaviour that you were looking for, let me know and I'll open a chat on Stack Overflow so we can sort out exactly what you need and solve the issue.

Comment: That new fix worked great! Thank you for your help on this and very well explained answers. I can finally move on with my life. HAHA.

Comment: It took a while to me as well to get into Nova and understand its mechanics. Thankfully the source code is really well written and you can find out some nice stuffs /tips/tricks by just looking into it